# .NET - Ensuring cross-thread event handling will not throw exception after form was disposed

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

On my .NET application, I have a thread running all the time in the background, that will raise events when a specific data arrives at the serial port. 
The raised event contains the progress of an operation (a calibration) being performed by the hardware connected to that port.

I want to display the progress of this operation to the user, so I created a Form with a progress bar named `ProgressBarCal`.
In order to synchronize the operation with the GUI, I am using the `Form.BeginInvoke()`

The problem is that as the background thread outlives the form, it could generate events while the form is being disposed, resulting in an `ObjectDisposedException` when doing `ProgressBarCal.Value = e.progress`.
I decided to use the following strategy to avoid an exception being thrown:

```
Private Sub OnCalibrationProgressReport(sender As Object, e As CalibrationEventArgs)

    If InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(Sub() OnCalibrationProgressReport(sender, e))
        Return
    End If

    Try
        If e.timeout Then 'if the operation timeout we tell user
            MessageBox.Show("Calibration timeout.")
        Else
            ProgressBarCal.Value = e.progress 'otherwise we display progress
        End If
    Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException When Me.IsDisposed
        'ignore this exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

Using `When Me.IsDisposed` after the `Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException` will make sure that only the ObjectDisposedException that I want to ignore (based in my question) are ignored, therefore making this code reliable?

Comment: You are apparently registering the event handler using `AddHandler`. The fact that there's an issue is exactly why you are supposed to use `RemoveHandler` EVERY time you use `AddHandler`.  If you use `AddHandler` in a form then you should be using `RemoveHandler` when you close the form and the issue goes away.

Comment: Have you considered using e.g. a `BackgroundWorker` or something like that that's *built* for having background work report progress back to the UI thread?

Comment: Sorry... I am using RemoveHandler. I actually wrote the wrong code in the original question. Your idea is correct, but works only with Invoke() not with BeginInvoke(). In the BeginInvoke I still could have the message pump to call the handler after the form has been disposed.

Comment: Is there a reason the background thread should be alive after your form closes or is it consequence of how you wrote the code?  Ideally, your background thread code would have some shutdown logic that you could call.  If it is monitoring a serial port, presumably it also opened said port;  as such it should be properly closing that port.

Comment: yes, the main reason is that the serial port is used by many different forms and also logs data, so I cant keep creating and destroying that background object. The object is disposed and port closed before the application exits.